# Subset of N larger than N?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $S=\{\prod{n}:n\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\})\}$. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic yields that $\prod{n}\neq\prod{k}$ where $n,k\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\})$ and $n\neq k$. Wouldn't this mean that $|S|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\})|=\aleph_1$? But $S$ contains only numbers in $\mathbb{N}$, thus $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}\implies |S|\leq\aleph_0$? (Sorry if I'm confusing, or missing something obvious; I have no formal education in set theory). Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$\prod \{2,6\} = \prod \{3,4\}$$ Beyond that, you can take the product only for finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistakes here.

First, your claim via FTA is false: that only holds if we're taking the product of a set of *primes*. This is a minor problem, though, since we can just replace $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ with $\mathbb{P}$, the set of primes.

Second - and fatally - *not* every set of primes yields a natural number via the product! No product of an *infinite* set of primes is a natural number. So in fact, all you've shown is that the set of *finite sets* of primes is countable - which is indeed true.

Finally - although this isn't really relevant - you implicitly assume that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$. This is **not** necessarily true, and is known as the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis). $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of *countable ordinals*, which consistently with ZFC could have *smaller* cardinality than $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. That is, we could have $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$. It is known that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$ - that is, the reals are uncountable - but the exact value of $2^{\aleph_0}$ is [impossible to determine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#Independence_from_ZFC) from [the usual axioms of set theory alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

Comment: Hmm... We could write $\mathbb{N}=\{1, 1+1, 1+1+1,...\}$. By your reasoning some of those elements wouldn't be natural numbers? What is the difference between the products in $S$ and sums in $N$?

Comment: @TommyRäjert No, each of those elements would be natural numbers - *since each of those elements is a **finite** sum*. The thing "1+1+1+..." is *not* be a natural number. The difference isn't between products and sums, it's between *finite* combinations and *infinite* combinations.

Comment: @TommyRäjert Note that amongst the sets of primes, there are infinite sets - like the set $\mathbb{P}$ of *all* primes. My point is that the "products" corresponding to these sets *aren't actually natural numbers* - e.g. what's the product of all the primes?

Comment: What's the sum of $|\mathbb{N}|$ 1's? Sorry, I don't see the difference yet

Comment: @TommyRäjert It isn't anything. It doesn't make sense to add up infinitely many $1$s. There is no natural number which is that sum. Again: in general, infinite sums of natural numbers aren't natural numbers, and infinite products of natural numbers aren't natural numbers.

Comment: @TommyRäjert Let's start at the beginning. Do you understand why "$1+1+1+1+...$" is not a natural number?

Comment: Yes, and $1*2*3*4*...$ is not a natural number either...

Comment: @TommyRäjert Exactly. *That's my point*. So $S$ is **not a set of natural numbers**.

Comment: @TommyRäjert: Perhaps it's time you study some set theory.

Comment: So I cannot write N as a sum, similar to the one I did?

Comment: @TommyRäjert You can write $\mathbb{N}$ as a *set of* sums, but that does not mean that it *is a* sum.